# How to send email without providing my emailid and password in node js(nodemailer)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

i want to use gmail smtp server to send welcome email when user create an account . welcome email must be send through my gmail id without providing my Email , password in auth section. my code is here..

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '*****@gmail.com',
    pass: *****
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: AFAIK, you're going to need to authorize the account in order to send email through gmail's servers. Otherwise, this would allow spam companies to send mountains of spam through gmail's servers.

Comment: @JLowther read my question again..

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your username and password through environment variables such as

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.NODEMAILER_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.NODEMAILER_PASSWORD
  }
});
```

Which can be set before running your process in linux like

```
NODEMAILER_USERNAME=test@gmail.com&&NODEMAILER_PASSWORD=pass&&./node www/bin
```

Alternatively you might be able to use an API key (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs), but if you want to avoid storing it in your code it would be the same approach.

Comment: this is prob the easiest way you'll find... it's the closest you'll get without having to "hard code" your username and password into your code. either this or read from a file somewhere, which using dotenv is easier...

Comment: how to get API key?